# javascript does not work with pagination

Tags: javascript

am doing pagination of table in php with phtml.The problem is I have a javascript to change the color of the row.It works only for my first page,doesnt work with other pages.

```
foreach($this->paginator as $record)
       {echo "<td width='61'> <a href='#' class='test'  data-id='" . $record['id']. "'>". $record['id'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='61'  >". $record['firstname'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width='61'>" . $record['emailid'] . "</a></td>";
       echo "<td width='38'>" . $record['customdata'] . "</td>";
}
```

Javascript is

```
function approve(id) {

   var id =id;  
   $.ajax({
       url: 'http://localhost/feedback/public/index/approve/',
       type: 'POST',                    
       data:"id="+id,
       success:function(data) {
                 alert('Approved successfully');
                     var index =parseFloat(id)+1;                                    
                    $('table tr:eq('+index+')').css("background-color", "54FF9F");//this           works only for first page
                    }
           })   
    }
```

I'm calling javascript in onclick of a button in popup window.Can anyone help me y it doesnot work for other pages

Answer (score 0):

Your `success` function is what is coloring the rows; by adding inline styles to the `tr` tags themselves. Because this function (in all likelihood) does not run again when you go to the next page of your table, the newly rendered rows do not get colored.

I would recommend adding a class to the rows instead, and adding the CSS rule to a stylesheet.

```
$('table tr:eq('+index+')').addClass('alt-row');
```

CSS:

```
.alt-row td { background-color: #54FF9F; }
```

Also, to play it safe, I apply background colors to cells, not rows, as some older browsers do not support backgrounds on table rows.

Comment: Right; sorry, Monday morning brain-lapse. Am I correct in assuming your pagination is occuring on the back end; i.e. each time the user goes to a new page of the table, a new request is made and a new set of rows is returned? Can you add a class to the table rows on the backend, before the response is returned to the client?